# How do I start a console session with my $5 Cisco router through the RS-232 port?

Tags: command-line

I just acquired a cheap-o $5 Cisco 831 router with what would appear to be a custom configuration which does not allow me to access the router using "Cisco Router Web Setup (CRWS) software" via `http://10.10.10.1` as described by Cisco's [831 documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/831/hardware/installation/guide/install.html#wp1053985).

Searching for "console" and "connection" I found [Connecting to the Console Port with Linux](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/connectedgrid/cgr1000/hardware/cgr1240/app.console.html#wp1049053) which is great, but the instructions are for a different router and do not apply to this unit.

And the rabbit hole goes deep after that. 
I found a manual, [Cisco 800 Series Software Configuration Guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/12836711/Cisco-800-Series-Software-Configuration-Guide#download) with over 500 pages of info. I looked for the obvious short goal, "reset" + "factory" + "defaults" and didn't find anything.

Help me get started, and please describe how to connect to the router via CLI/console session.

Comment: use `minicom -o -s` as terminal emulator

Comment: Why should that help?

Comment: Is this not the CLI command/app to use to access the router?

Comment: Did you try a 30/30/30?

Comment: @jet. Minicom was the clue that helped me find other help pages on google. This blog is a [good example](http://fadils.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/how-to-connect-to-cisco-routers-using-minicom/) because it explains how to get the connection name. As it turned out my system has two tty settings in dmesg, but trial and error found the correct one. Post something like this and I'll give you the "answer" points (and at a paltry 1759 rep, you could use the points...hahah

Comment: Also, having the console cable connected, minicom running and then powering the Cisco router was useful, because I was then able to see the router initialize itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`minicom -o -s`

This is modem control and terminal emulation program for Unix and Unix like OS

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to a Cisco console port is pretty generic across all platforms with regards to the serial settings.  The directions you found should point you in the right direction, but you may have to look up directions to connect to a serial console for your specific operating system and installed applications (you don't specify). Especially keep in mind that the specific reference to the serial port may be different on your OS and whether it is a true serial port or a USB-serial adapter.

As for the reset directions, here is the [Cisco Password Recovery Procedure](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps380/products_password_recovery09186a00800942bc.shtml) for the 831.

Good luck and welcome to the world of Cisco.

Comment: USB to serial is problematic as most are wired for 8 pins only. Last time I checked, serial required 9. USB to serial may be fine if the hardware doesn't use all 9 pins and the 8 pins are not missing any required pins.

Comment: @sunk818, since Cisco typically uses an 8 conductor rollover cable to connect to the console port, this is not a problem.