# Does Cisco 831 router need to dynamically serve IP to use Cisco Router Web Setup?

Tags: dhcp

I'm trying to get this $5 Cisco 831 Router up. I've managed to tty into the hardware setup. This launched [System configuration dialog](http://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/workbooks/ccna/cisco-device-initial-configuration-dialog) (I used this link's same setup). Since the unit didn't have a password and launched this setup utility, can I assume its in a default state?

So why is this unit not serving DHCP IPs? I feel like I'm in a sort of in a catch 22. The quickstart documentation says to connect the client to the router at one of the 4 standard ports. Using a browser, point it to 10.10.10.1 (and following that link's instructions I also tried 10.1.1.1) and use this address to access Cisco Router Web Setup--but there is no connection.

On the Linux side I've deactivated CentOS's NetworkManager and use `ifcfg-eth0` and the command `/etc/init.d/network restart` to [start ethernet manually as described here](http://blog.roozbehk.com/post/35156862882/redhat-add-network-eth). This works to obtain an IP from my Belkin router. But when I switch to the Cisco box and do the same the client keeps looking for the Belkin router and not the one its connected to. I commented out the Linux file `/etc/resolv.conf` to reset this preference. Still, none of my attempts to get a Dynamic IP from the Cisco router ever populate this file with the Cisco router info. I've edited `/etc/sysconfig/network` to provide the 10.1.1.1 default gateway. And I [installed `dhclient`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-renew-dhcp-client-ip-address/) which says its supposed to renew dhcp and obtain a new ip. Nothing is changing the ping statistics always reporting the Belkin gateway ip.

So in my Cisco-newbieness I'm suspecting the 831 doesn't serve DHCP out of box. But how then is CRWS supposed to connect via 10.10.10.1 if it doesn't create some IP lease automatically? Which is so strange to me I think its my setup--but I can't think of anything else...

---

As requested, I attempted the command but only produced errors. While I try to uncover the reason, here is the [output from the router while it booted up](http://pastebin.com/rh6mSySh). Maybe it contains some pertient information.

---

Got it. Here is the [output](http://pastebin.com/XBFu3MUT).

Comment: If you can tty in, then do a `show run` and add the result to your question.

Comment: `show run` must be executed in enable mode, so type `enable` first.

Comment: That's about as empty as a Cisco config can be. There are no interface definitions, no DHCP pool is configured. You'll need to configure the interfaces first, then configure DHCP pool with addresses which match the interface you want to use DHCP on.

Comment: Darn. How then is the router supposed to be configurable via HTTP for the novice user? Following the reset advice from [my other post on this topic](http://superuser.com/questions/685100/how-do-i-start-a-console-session-with-my-5-cisco-router-through-the-rs-232-port/692976?noredirect=1#692976) I followed the reset instructions. But the HTTP config page 10.10.10.1 (or 10.1.1.1) does not connect. Is there something in the posted output to explain why I can't get the router into HTTP config mode?

Comment: The only real difference between my output and the [reset](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps380/products_password_recovery09186a00800942bc.shtml) output example is `#show ip interface brief` only shows `Ethernet0` and `Ethernet1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This router is not running the default software. It may not even have an HTTP server. If you want to configure a DHCP server, you'll need to actually do it. It may be helpful to search around for sample configurations for your router. A plain configuration does nothing -- no DHCP, no http server, nothing.